# Select count of duplicated rows returns wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates

I have a table with 82,535 rows, where 65,087 rows are unique by ID. When I pull the entire result set of 82,535 and copy to Excel and remove duplicates, it shows that there are 17,448 duplicates. But when I'm using the query below I'm getting different results:

```
SELECT
    BLD_ID, COUNT(BLD_ID) AS [BLD_ID COUNT] 
FROM
    Project.BreakageAnalysisOutcome_SentToAIM 
GROUP BY 
    BLD_ID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(BLD_ID) > = 2
```

This query returns a value of 17,364

[image]

I know for sure that the number of unique `BLD_ID` is 65,087

Comment: You could have some that are triplicate or more.  This would change the count.  Run the query again with "Having count(BLD_ID) > = 3"

Comment: How did you calculate 17,364 from your query? From your query, Number of duplicates should be sum([BLD_ID COUNT]) - (number of row fetch) so you should rewrite it to get the right number.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely reason fro that is duplicate record may have more than 2 occurrence.

find duplicate count

```
Select  COUNT(BLD_ID)- COUNT( DISTINCT BLD_ID) 
From Project.BreakageAnalysisOutcome_SentToAIM
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE with a Row_Number Function instead of count with group by clause and filer by Row_Number > 1.

;WITH cte 
AS 
(
  SELECT ID, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS Rn
  FROM [Table1]
)
DELETE cte WHERE Rn > 1

Comment: How does a DELETE statement answer the question that was asked? The question doesn't mention removing rows with duplicate values.It asks about "Select count of duplicates".